# Error for connecting to Redis Cluster with node-redis cluster configuration. [ErrorReply: ERR Protocol error: unauthenticated multibulk length]

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, node-redis

This is not a Redis server error as I am able to connect to every other client without issue. However, I am getting an error with these connection settings in node-redis.

The error I keep getting is this. `[ErrorReply: ERR Protocol error: unauthenticated multibulk length]`

My setup is below and taking 1 node and connecting to that via the direct client works but this configuration is not working and I can't understand why. It's like the password isn't being passed through.

```js
this.client = createCluster({
        rootNodes: [
          {
            url: 'redis://ip.address.here:6379',
            username: 'default',
            password: 'password'
          },
          {
            url: 'redis://ip.address.here:6379',
            username: 'default',
            password: 'password'
          },
          {
            url: 'redis://ip.address.here:6379',
            username: 'default',
            password: 'password'
          },
          {
            url: 'redis://ip.address.here:6379',
            username: 'default',
            password: 'password'
          },
          {
            url: 'redis://ip.address.here:6379',
            username: 'default',
            password: 'password'
          },
          {
            url: 'redis://ip.address.here:6379',
            username: 'default',
            password: 'password'
          },
        ]
});
```

Comment: What is the redis version you're using? Also, are you using ACL in your redis cluster?

Comment: @RahulSharma 7.0.4 no acl

Comment: Try setting `url` to this: `'redis://default:password@ip.address.here:6379'` and remove `username` and `password` from each object. Optionally, you can also remove any three of the rootNode objects.

Comment: I did that. It didn't work.